# Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization

Tags: windows, windows-10

Found message `some settings are hidden or managed by your organization` while getting to wi-fi settings:

[image]

I'm not logged into any organisation domain or MS account. Why I'm getting this message?

My diagnostic data is set to "full":

[image]

Comment: Did you change any group policy settings?

Comment: I did not change group policy since I can't find how to do that : https://superuser.com/questions/1386203/change-group-policy-settings But I think I should not have message with default settings?