# Change group policy settings

Tags: windows-10

Can't find how to change group policy settings on my 64 bit Windows 10 Home. Trying to run command `gpedit` on my PC, but system founds nothing related to that. My other computer executes this commands correctly. How to enable this command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default it is not available on Windows 10 home edition, but you can enable it by running these batch file codes with **administrator rights**

```
@echo off 
pushd "%~dp0" 

dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~3*.mum >List.txt 
dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~3*.mum >>List.txt 

for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . List.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i" 
pause
```

process will take couple of minutes after you can run **gpedit.msc** to check it.

you don't need to restart computer but it is recommended to restart

Comment: In my case, the new packages (although installed) were unusable until I rebooted.